# Show identical lines when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to show the lines hidden by the "*n identical lines skipped*" message?

I reached [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8256784) from the suggested edits queue.  The author was asking somebody to edit the post to fix the formatting, so I went into the markdown view to see if the edit addressed the issue.  Unfortunately, I can't tell because the message "13 identical lines skipped" prevents me from trying to infer what the author wanted.

My usual method for viewing markdown is to go to the main post and click "Edit", but unfortunately that just takes me back into the (abridged) review pane.

I'm completely new to reviewing edits, so it's possible I'm simply missing something trivial.  Help?

Comment: I agree with this - it's also important to see so that you know the suggestion covers everything it should. There's been the occasional edit where I've kicked myself for accepting due to not being able to see the rest of the post in question.

Comment: A quirk in this case, seen only by looking at revision history, is that the only formatting left to fix was in those trailing edit appendixes — the author had done the rest already.

Comment: Two years later, I still agree with this request. I stumbled across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16381966), which clearly demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting `Rendered output` shows all of the lines.

[image]

Comment: If the formatting is messed up, then the rendered and markdown won't be the same; you need access to both to fix it.  My psychic markdown abilities haven't progressed to the point I can tell the MD text by looking at the rendered output.